# Problems with FontFamily when a wpf is published

Tags: wpf, font-family

I use the FontFamily="Swiss 721" in the whole application and I have a problem when it is installed in other machine , that doen't have the Visual Studio 2010 installed. The problem is  that the text doesn't appear using Swiss 721, it appears with a default font family (Times New Roman).

Any idea¿?¿

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've visual studio 2010 installed but I don't have a 'swiss 721' font. 
Googling for it I see that isn't a royalty-free font.
For distribute it with your application you need to pay some license to the productor:

[BitStream](http://www.paratype.com/btstore/fonts/Swiss-721.htm)